# Detach object from context with all navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to save related objects to database. Saving, updating works good.
My scenario is adding list of data to context,
afterwards validating added data before save or update, *remove records which fail validation* from context
and *insert or update others*. There a lot of navigation properties in my parent data, so I want that when 
I remove parent object from context **all its navigational properties** should also be removed from context.
But by saying "removing data from context" **doesn't mean** that I also want to **remove it from underlying database**.
Scenarios which I have tried so far:

**I. First option**

```
//Get the object context to be able to use Detach
//Because I use code first
System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext taxesObjectContext = 
         ((IObjectContextAdapter)myContext).ObjectContext;

//Detach entity from context to not update it
taxesObjectContext.Detach(parentEntity);
```

**The problem**: It only detaches the parentEntity itself, so *navigational properties are still there*.

**II. Second option**

```
myContext.Entry(parentEntity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;
```

**The problem**: It only detaches the parentEntity itself, so *navigational properties are still there*.

**III. Third option**

```
//EntityType is type of parent entity
myContext.Set<EntityType>().Local.Remove(parentEntity);
```

**The problem**: This scenario works well when data not exists in database. When it already exists
removing record from local also *removes it from underlying database*.

**Question**: How can I remove parent entity from local context (because it is already added) with all
its navigational properties but still not deleting it from underlying database?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any method to *detach object with all its navigation propeties*. Since my goal is to remove records which have not pass validation and I *don't send any delete query to database* I solved my problem like below:

**I.** Adding validation failed records to error log table

**II.** Then, I remove validation failed records from context:

```
private void RemoveFromContext<EntityType>(List<EntityType> entityList)
            where EntityType : class
{
    if (entityList != null && entityList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (EntityType entity in entityList)
        {                  
            myContext.Set<EntityType>().Local.Remove(entity);                    
        }
    }
}
```

**III.** Finally, I am detaching all deleted records, because deleted records are that records which have failed validation

```
private void DetachRemovedRecords()
{
    //Get object context to be able to detach entities
    System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext myObjectContext =
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)myContext).ObjectContext;

    IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> deletedRecords =
        taxesObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
        System.Data.EntityState.Deleted);

    if (deletedRecords != null
        && deletedRecords.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (ObjectStateEntry stateEntry in deletedRecords)
        {
            if (stateEntry != null
                && stateEntry.Entity != null)
            {
                myObjectContext.Entry(stateEntry.Entity).State =
                       System.Data.EntityState.Detached;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to @FarhadJabiyev for hint.